# How would a native speaker ask for ID and reason for stay?

Tags: translation

My Japanese is pretty basic, but I know enough to know context matters. So the speaker in this would be a customs officer, like at airport security, speaking to a passenger entering the country. I assume that would dictate a more formal address, with it being a professional on the clock and doing their job.

So how would they say:

> “Welcome to Ōijima City. Identification and reason for visit, please.”

In case clear distinctions are useful. It's a man speaking, and they're not being gruff about it.

I've already checked google translate and it offered me this:

> 大井島市へようこそ。 訪問の身分証明書と理由をお願いします。
> Ōi-jima-shi e yōkoso. Hōmon no mibun shōmei-sho to riyū o onegaishimasu.

Is this more or less what I'm going for? (for context, it's for a story, so it's not a city I'm aware of actually existing)

Comment: I think it is ok, but you should stick to grouping at English level. You are asking (1) id and (2) reason for visit, the current translation is asking "id of visit" and "reason".

Comment: @sundowner Thanks.